# create multiple persistent volumes in Kubernetes at a time?

Tags: kubernetes, storage

Can we create multiple persistent volumes at a time through CSI ? Basically storage supports number of clones to be created from a source. I want to see if I can leverage this through CSI so that I will have just 1 call to create 10 clones.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Give us a bigger picture, preferably with a reproducible example. Which tools, environments are you using and what exactly you want to achieve with them?

Comment: I dont want the controller - CreateVolume method to be called 10 times if I want 10 clones. Because the storage provider supports creating multiple clones with a single call. I can specify the number of clones that need to be created. So, from CSI plugin I want to call storage provider only 1 time when I want to create mutiple clones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic volume provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) to have PV's created on demand.

Comment: Suppose I add a field "numberOfClones" in the storage class object and use it to dynamically create pvc. I will get the field "numberOfClones" in my CSI CreateVolume method. And storage can create 10 clones and return it. But how will K8s attach the 10 volume ids to pvc/pv ?

Comment: You do not need "numberOfClones" for dynamic provisioning to work. So do not use it, unless you really mean it. If you configure your cluster to do so, it will automatically provision using your dynamic provisioning configuration, exactly how this happens depends on which way you choose to configure the dynamic provisioning. Configuration choices, details of what k8s is doing, and how to configure your storage class and pvc's to implement dynamic provisioning are in the link provided in the answer.